# What is the difference between 2 forms of specialization template implementation in c++

Tags: c++, templates

There are 2 different specialization template forms in c++

One is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class mytest
{
public:

    void method(T input){}
};


template<>
void mytest<int>::method(int input)
{
    cout << "ok" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    mytest<bool> mt;
    mt.method(1);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The other is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class mytest
{
public:

    void method(T input){}
};


void mytest<int>::method(int input)
{
    cout << "ok" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    mytest<bool> mt;
    mt.method(1);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

They can also be compiled in VS2013. I notice that the second implementation of specialization template situation is just lack of  `template<>`

I want to know what the difference is between the 2 forms above.

Comment: template<> is optional when fully specialising - the second will not work if there were was another deduced template argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual C++ is wrong.

The standard is very clear about this.

First,

> Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the
>   same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the template<>
>   syntax.

Meaning that, for explicit specialization of a class template, the member definition strictly do not require template<>.

Example:

```
template<class T> 
struct A {
};

template<> 
struct A<int> {
  void f(int);
};

// template<> not used for a member of an
// explicitly specialized class template
void A<int>::f(int) { / ... / }
```

And,

> A member or a member template of a class template may be explicitly
>   specialized for a given implicit instantiation of the class template,
>   even if the member or member template is defined in the class template
>   definition. An explicit specialization of a member or member template
>   is specified using the syntax for explicit specialization.

Meaning that, for a template that is not "explicit specialized", you can specialize its member, with the template<> (syntax for explicit specialization)

Example,

```
template<class T> 
struct A {
  void f(T);
};


// specialization
template<> 
void A<int>::f(int);
```

The above examples are directly copied out from standard. To summarize, if the class is already explicitly specialized, do not use template<>, else if the class relies on implicit instantiation, use template<>.

Your first example compiles fine in Clang, and your second example fails to compile in Clang, you will get an error:

> error: template specialization requires 'template<>'

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T> class mycontainer { ... };
template <> class mycontainer <char> { ... };
```

The first line is the generic template, and the second one is the specialization.

When we declare specializations for a template class, we must also define all its members, even those identical to the generic template class, because there is no "inheritance" of members from the generic template to the specialization.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: the question asks why `template<>` is sometimes missing (because it is optional when fully specialising)